# retrieval of GPS tracker data to web service

Tags: gps, modem, tcp, gprs

I am trying to create a web service that retrieves my GPS tracking device data.
Let's say for example that I want to create a simple web page that shows me my GPS tracker location by it's coordinate each moment.

I made a little research and found out that I need a server that will accept GPRS input and will parse the data to tcp/ip. 
I am not sure what I can do with this information. The best solution for me would be to use a cloud service that could do this for me.

If not, Do I need to purchase a GPRS modem?

I'd be happy to hear about different solutions that would make it easy for me to create my web service using the GPS tracker.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this? I am looking for something similar. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I can comment as an owner (and developer) of GPS tracking solution. The basic things you will need:

- GPS tracker with GPRS connectivity.
- GPS tracker communication
  protocol (often they are proprietary and will cost you extra)
- Protocol implementation on the server side
- Web based application to
  display the current device position.

The development process will take you at least couple of months. 
Cheapest way is to buy the device monitoring service from your local provider. This will save you money and effort.

Comment: Hi Funtik, Thanks for the answer. I am speaking from a web developer point of view with no knowledge in the protocol implementation side. My main concern is regarding creating the connectivity between the GPS tracker and the protocol implementation on the server side. If I understand your answer correctly, I can buy a monitoring service from my local provider? If I do this, The local provider will receive the data from my GPS tracker and what data type will he be sending me to my web server?

Comment: If you buy the service, you'll get the access to web-application and will be able to monitor it from there. Usually providers do not expose any protocols to share "raw" data.

Comment: Why do you want to implement it from scratch?? What's your goal?

Comment: My goal is to use the tracker current location in order to create a web service that uses google maps api for directions to supply live navigation.

Comment: I suppose the best solution would be a service that supplies an API that would let me get access to the data.

Comment: LIVE navigation is not possible because of delays introduced by tracker / server implementation. The best you can get is 1-2 minute delays between the time tracker moves and time you get the information about the move (and that's not usable in case of LIVE navigation)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49836/discussion-between-funtik-and-nimi)

Comment: Hi I have same type of issue. I need to know about any GPS tracker which gives location using Webservice. Right now I get to know about several gps tracker which works with SMS. Can you suggest me any tracker which   can send location to my server periodically?